# rotateing without using XML animation file

Tags: android, xml

i want rotate a image without use xml file.

it is my xml animation code:

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="10000"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:startOffset="0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
/>
```

Comment: google animation+rotation+programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 View needRotateView;// That needRotateView must make sure had measured
 float w = needRotateView.getWidth();
 float h = needRotateView.getHeight();
 int type = Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF;//sorry,if not work find,try the
```

follow type value

```
// int value_type = Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT;
// int value_type = Animation.ABSOLUTE;
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, type, w / 2, type,h / 2);
anim.setDuration(1000 * 10);
anim.setFillAfter(false);
anim.setStartOffset(0);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Answer (score 0):

A real easy way is to use a ProgressBar item and set it to use your drawable:

Add a ProgressBar widget to your layout (mine is in a RelativeLayout):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/mp4_progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_anim" />
```

The last line points to a drawable XML, like this:

```
// progress_spinner_anim.xml
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080" />
```

That file points to your image file (mine is drawable/spinner.png).

Comment: i can control speed rotating at this way?